# Handling the Broadcasting without loosing info (2d array and 3d array operations)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

I have a SDF which is a 2d numpy array and also an image feature array which is a 3d array, it has the various texture in the third dimension. So in my equation I have this:

```
    ux = np.sum(cv2.blur(phi0*txtre, (3, 3)))/np.sum(cv2.blur(phi0, (3, 3)))
    vx = np.sum(cv2.blur((1-phi0)*txtre, (3, 3)))/np.sum(cv2.blur((1-phi0), (3, 3)))
    a = (txtre - ux)**2
    b = (txtre - vx)**2
    dphidt = dirac(phi) * (cv2.blur((a - b), (3, 3)))

    phi += (dt * dphidt) #dt is just to maintain CFL condition
```

Here I have **phi0** which is a heavside of SDF and is 2d array, and **txtre** which is a 3d array. however this line gives me broadcasting error.

Also later I need to take gradient and update the *phi* (SDF) with small change in *phi* called *dphidt*. So how to handle all the broadcasting?

Here *dirac* function is defined as follows

```
    def dirac(p):
    out = np.abs(p) <= 0.5
```

Comment: Try : `cv2.blur(phi0[...,None]*txtre, (3, 3))`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But later in code i have : `dphidt = dirac(phi[...,None]) * (cv2.blur(c, (3, 3)))` , followed by `phi += (dt * dphidt)` for which i get an error _non-broadcastable output operand with shape (517,437,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (517,437,20)_

Comment: Please those additional details into the question as they not readable in comments.

Comment: yeah have updated the Question

Comment: I can't comment on the edited codes, as I don't know what's `dirac`, specifically what it expects as inputs.

Comment: @Divakar i'm sry, i have updated the Question once more

Comment: For the edited codes : `dirac(phi0[...,None]) * (cv2.blur((a-b), (3, 3)))` seem to work.

Comment: for edited code. evrything seems to work fine except the line *phi += (dt * dphidt)* . Here i get the error as i have mentioned in second comment

Comment: Reading the [`docs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) would go a long way.